# SSRS Sorting the PIe Chart data value

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a pie chart that has a calculate Result value in percentage (%).  I need to sort the % value from highest to lowest. I found the CategoryGroups->Sort Expression from Chart Properties, but it is not allowing me to put a sort expression.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I want to sort my pie charts, I set the `Category Group` `Sort by` value to the same expression as the pie chart's `Value`.  This way the biggest sections will appear first and the smallest sections will appear last.

For instance, if I my pie chart is showing *Total Sales* I will set the `Value` to `SUM(total_sales)`.  Then I open the `Category Group` and go the `Sorting` tab and click the `FX` button to set the sort order to the function.  I use the function `=Sum(Fields!total_sales.Value)`.

Comment: @Arsee glad to hear it!  Please mark my answer so other people know it was the right answer.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out :)  Thank you!